# Rename all files in directory and (deeply nested) sub-directories

Tags: bash, shell, unix

What is the shell command for renaming all files in a directory and sub-directory (recursively)?

I would like to add an underscore to all the files ending with `*scss` from `filename.scss` to `_filename.scss` in all the directories and sub-directories.

I have found answers relating to this but most if not all require you to know the filename itself, and I do not want this because the filenames differ and are a lot to know by heart or even type them manually and some of them are deeply nested in directories.

Comment: Try a find with a loop

Comment: Find works well in finding the files but won't work when I want to rename the found file (the filename is not emitted)

Comment: I have tried this `find ./src/components -iname "*.scss"` and this gets the files but then how would I get each filename and append an underscore to it?
Something like

`find ./src/components -iname "*.scss" | mv each-file-name to _each-file-name`?

Also, find, finds everything, so not sure if within a loop this would make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I was under the impression that the `bash -c` bit was somehow necessary for multiple expansion of the found element; anubhava's answer proved me wrong. I am leaving that bit in the answer for now as it worked for the OP.

```
find . -type f -name *scss -exec bash -c 'mv $1 _$1' -- {} \;
```

- `find .` -- find in current directory (recursively)
- `-type f` -- files
- `-name *scss` -- matching the pattern `*scss`
- `-exec` -- execute for each element found
- `bash -c '...'` -- execute command in a subshell
- `--` -- end option parsing
- `{}` -- expands to the name of the element found (which becomes the positional parameter for the `bash -c` command)
- `\;` -- end the `-exec` command

Comment: `exec` or `execdir`?

Comment: Super! It worked, but had to use `execdir` because I think `exec` would not execute within directory.

Comment: @brandNew: With `-exec` you would get full paths to the element relative to the source directory, i.e. `mv ./foo/bar/baz.scss ./foo/bar/_baz.scss`. With `-execdir` you go to the subdirectory of the element for execution of the command, i.e. `mv baz.scss _baz.scss`. Either way works; the man page for `find` recommends the latter. I admit to not knowing about `-execdir` until just now myself. You live and learn. ;-)

Comment: Absolutely. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-execdir` option here:

```
find ./src/components -iname "*.scss" -execdir mv {} _{} \;
```

Comment: The first answer worked. But this is useful too (would have worked), so upvote!

Comment: OK... now I have to backtrack and find out why I believed that you can have only one `{}` per `-exec` and you need that `bash -c` bit for multiple expansions. ?:-\

Comment: @DevSolar: I wouldn't have posted if it didn't work. It worked fine on my Mac's `find`

Answer (score 1):

You are close to a solution:

```
find ./src/components -iname "*.scss" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -I{} mv {} _{}
```

In this approach, the "loop" is executed by xargs. I prefer this solution overt the usage of the -exec in find. The syntax is clear to me.

Also, if you want to repeat the command and avoid double-adding the underscore to the already processed files, use a regexp to get only the files not yet processed:

```
find ./src/components -iregex ".*/[^_][^/]*\.scss" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -I{} mv {} _{}
```

By adding the -print0/-0 options, you also avoid problems with whitespaces.

Comment: The first answer worked. But this is useful too (would have worked), so upvote!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

EXTENSION='.scss'
cd YOURDIR

find . -type f | while read -r LINE; do
  FILE="$( basename "$LINE" )"

  case "$LINE" in
    *"$EXTENSION")
      DIRNAME="$( dirname "$LINE" )"
      mv -v "$DIRNAME/$FILE" "$DIRNAME/_$FILE"
    ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the question has been answered and the answer accepted. In future, please consider explaining why something works instead of just a straight solution or answer to  a problem or question :). 
Cheers.